# So fast, it melts the ice off?

Tags: aerodynamics, airspeed, deice

Approximately, how fast would an aircraft have to travel through freezing air to melt the ice off the wing, propellers, or rotor blades?

Comment: Couple more variables you'll probably need: Altitude (alternatively, air pressure), and dew point.

Comment: Please confirm you mean "melt" as opposed to just 'get rid of...'.  Because ice will sublimate at pretty low speeds if the air is dry.  Also, temperature is a key variable.  "Freezing air" can be 32F down to absolute zero.

Comment: Longer than a minute, less than an hour.  That's about as precise an answer as you're going to get with so many variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already done in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/83551/33692), we can [calculate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_air_temperature) the True Air Temperature (TAT) that the aircraft's skin will feel from the Static Air Temperature (SAT) and the Mach number:

$$ \frac{\text{TAT}}{\text{SAT}} = 1 + \frac{\gamma - 1}{2} M^2 = 1 + \frac{1}{5} M^2 $$

(using $ \gamma = 1.4 $ for air). For different SATs the curves then look like this:

[image: TAT for different SAT]

I added a dashed line at a TAT of 10°C because this is the limit defined for *icing conditions*. At higher TATs, the ice should definitely melt (although it could already start melting before). We can now obtain the intersection Mach number as a function of SAT by inverting the formula above:

$$ M = \sqrt{5 \left( \frac{\text{TAT}}{\text{SAT}} - 1 \right)} $$

The resulting curve looks like this:

[image: Mach required]

As you can see, a Mach number between ~0.4 and ~1.3 will be required to melt ice, depending on the SAT.